# jQuery Dynamic $.post ajax call

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run an ajax $.post call on a script that builds a form dynamically. How would i go about doing this. Currently the psudocode looks like this:

//I Would build the ajaxString with a foreach loop, looping through all of the inputs on //the page. The following is psudocode,

var ajaxString;
for each inputs {
ajaxstring += "field i: \"\" + $(\"#frame\").contents().find(\":input:eq(i)\").val() +\"\"";

}
$.post("dynamicScript.php",{ "" + ajaxString + ""

//Right now this is how it works normally
//field 1: "" + $("#frame").contents().find(":input:eq(0)").val() +"",
//field 2: "" + $("#frame").contents().find(":input:eq(1)").val() +"", 
//field 3: "" + $("#frame").contents().find(":input:eq(2)").val() +"", 
//field 4_check: "" + $("#frame").contents().find(":input:eq(3)").val() +""
                            },function(data) {

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  As a note, if you indent your code section 4 spaces, it will do syntax highlighting for you to make it much easier to read!

Comment: I know this is really old but you should also accept the best answer for your question.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, using the serialize function. here is the code

$.post("dynamicScript.php", $("#frame").contents().find("#SubmitForm").serialize(),
                                function(data) {
                                                                 });

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the jquery method called [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).  It will return a query string of all the inputs in the form.

e.g. (a=1&b=2&c=foo)